# TTY switch for Ctrl-Alt F1 and Alt-F1...F6 in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, tty

**Is it possible...**

1. to have a terminal mode for the keybinding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>
2. to switch between TTYs for <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>...<kbd>F6</kbd>

Ubuntu has the above commands to move between different TTYs.

It seems that Mac does not have them activated.

**How can you activate the above functionalities in Mac?**

Comment: Are you booting in single user mode or something? What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: @Jason: I am trying to have code modes for me, such that I can just concentrate on coding and I see just black and green.

Comment: As the question title might be a bit confusing, the question is about switching between LINUX ttys in console mode, on a MAC computer not OS X.
And the answer by mandolo below does work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only one TTY (TTY1) is available in OSX. 
To enable tty use <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: That doesn't do anything??

Comment: It indeeds work on a Mac! Thanks for saving my day :D.

Comment: Answering the wrong question, but thanks for answering my question!

Comment: i, too, cannot find this desirable-but-hidden TTY

Comment: this is not true

Comment: what about newer models without a F1?

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure what you are asking. Are you asking about accessing TTYs in Mac OS X? That is not possible. Use the terminal, /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app

Comment: @Josh: Is there any similar kind of applications in Mac as TTYs which would allow me to have TTYs for OS X? - - It is hard for me to believe that you cannot access TTYs in OSX.

Comment: You can access them if you're not running Aqua. Is that what you want? I can provide a link to that, I've done it before.

Comment: @Masi does this help? http://www.macosxhints.com/article.php?story=20050617234017755&query=geektool

Comment: Yes, it helps. I am just wondering if the process isolation in your example without Aqua as good as with TTYs. I suspect.

Comment: @Josh Can you update the link? I'm interested in this.

Comment: @SevenBits try: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20020318020806482 or http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/85742/console-does-not-work

Answer (score 5):

For Mac/apple keyboard, on Linux system, press and hold `fn` first, then press `ctrl+opt+f2` for e.g. after that.

@mandolo was on the right track.

Comment: The question was about Mac OS X

Comment: my bad, didnt catch that minor detail.

Comment: in newer macbook there is no F1 keys